# Javascript / jquery hide show div

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#mybutton1").click(function(){
    $("#gamesyoumaylike").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
```

My toggle div (gamesyoumaylike) is automatically displaying when the page loads. how would i hide this automatically ?

Comment: You may simply make it hide by css or using `.hide()` with jQuery on page load!

Comment: Add css property at start, e.g. "display: none"

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS:

```
#gamesyoumaylike {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must do it with css. Add `"style='display:none'"` to your element

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="gamesyoumaylike" style="display:none;">...</div>
```